Color Transparency Not Consistent in Shiny Map
Link to the data is here. 
Hi I am developing a Shiny App. I have drop down menu with All options and the colors are consistent and transparent across the map. But I choose a particular city, it turns out into a more solid color with almost or no transparent. How can I modify the code. Here is my UI and Server code
 tabPanel("Interactive Map", icon = icon("map"),
           # Sidebar with a select input 
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               p("This app allows you to visualize the social vulnerability index in the city of Portland.
            Please choose the variables under the drop down menu."),
               # For Variable
               selectInput(inputId = "variable",
                           label = "Variable:",
                           choices = c("Overall SVI Ranking" = "RPL_THEMES",
                                       "Socioeconomic Status Theme Ranking" = "RPL_THEME1",
                                       "Household Characteristics Theme Ranking" = "RPL_THEME2",
                                       "Racial & Ethnic Minority Status Theme Ranking" = "RPL_THEME3",
                                       "Housing Type & Transportation Theme Ranking" = "RPL_THEME4",
                                       "Population Estimate" = "E_TOTPOP",
                                       "Housing Units Estimate" = "E_HU",
                                       "Households Estimate" = "E_HH",
                                       "Age 17 & Younger" = "EP_AGE17",
                                       "Age 65 & Older" = "EP_AGE65",
                                       "More People than Rooms" = "EP_CROWD",
                                       "Population with a Disability" = "EP_DISABL",
                                       "Persons in Group Quarters" = "EP_GROUPQ",
                                       "Housing Cost Burden" = "EP_HBURD",
                                       "Limited English Speaking" = "EP_LIMENG",
                                       "Minority" = "EP_MINRTY",
                                       "Mobile Homes" = "EP_MOBILE",
                                       "Housing with Multiple Units" = "EP_MUNIT",
                                       "No High School Diploma" = "EP_NOHSDP",
                                       "Households with No Vehicles" = "EP_NOVEH",
                                       "Below 150% Poverty" = "EP_POV150",
                                       "Single Parent Households" = "EP_SNGPNT",
                                       "Unemployment Rate" = "EP_UNEMP",
                                       "No Health Insurance" = "EP_UNINSUR"),
                           selected = "Overall SVI Ranking"),
               # For Base Map
               selectInput("basemap", 
                           label = "Basemap",
                           choices = c(
                             "All" = "All",
                             "Open Street Map" = "OpenStreetMap",
                             "CARTO Positron" = "CartoDB.Positron",
                             "CARTO Voyager" = "CartoDB.Voyager",
                             "Stadia Toner" = "Stadia.StamenToner"),
                           selected = "OpenStreetMap"),
               
               # For City
               selectInput("city",
                           label = "City:",
                           choices = c(
                             "All" = "All",
                             "Portland City" = "Portland",
                             "South Portland City" = "South Portland",
                             "Westbrook City" = "Westbrook"),
                           selected = "All"
                          ),
                 mainPanel(
               leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "700px"), 
               # Data source caption below the map
               tags$div(style = "text-align: right; font-size: 10px; margin-top: 10px;", 
                        tags$b("Data source:"),
                        "2018-2022 ACS, US Census Bureau"),
               width = 9
             )))

And this is my server code.
# Erase Water
  plsvi <- erase_water(svi, year = 2020) %>% st_make_valid()
  
  # Transform spatial data to WGS84
  sviwgs84 <- reactive({
    plsvi %>% st_transform(crs = 4326)
  })
  
  # Filter data based on city selection
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    if("All" %in% input$city){
      sviwgs84()
    } else {
    sviwgs84() %>% filter(CITY == input$city) 
    } 
  })
  
  
  # Map basemap names to their corresponding provider objects
  basemap_providers <- list(
    "OpenStreetMap" = providers$OpenStreetMap,
    "CartoDB.Positron" = providers$CartoDB.Positron,
    "CartoDB.Voyager" = providers$CartoDB.Voyager,
    "Stadia.StamenToner" = providers$Stadia.StamenToner
  )
  
  # Define the variable-label mapping using the choices vector
  variable_labels <- list(
    "RPL_THEMES" = "Overall SVI Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME1" = "Socioeconomic Status Theme Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME2" = "Household Characteristics Theme Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME3" = "Racial & Ethnic Minority Status Theme Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME4" = "Housing Type & Transportation Theme Ranking",
    "E_TOTPOP" = "Population Estimate",
    "E_HU" = "Housing Units Estimate",
    "E_HH" = "Households Estimate",
    "EP_AGE17" = "Age 17 & Younger",
    "EP_AGE65" = "Age 65 & Older",
    "EP_CROWD" = "More People than Rooms",
    "EP_DISABL" = "Population with a Disability",
    "EP_GROUPQ" = "Persons in Group Quarters",
    "EP_HBURD" = "Housing Cost Burden",
    "EP_LIMENG" = "Limited English Speaking",
    "EP_MINRTY" = "Minority",
    "EP_MOBILE" = "Mobile Homes",
    "EP_MUNIT" = "Housing with Multiple Units",
    "EP_NOHSDP" = "No High School Diploma",
    "EP_NOVEH" = "Households with No Vehicles",
    "EP_POV150" = "Below 150% Poverty",
    "EP_SNGPNT" = "Single Parent Households",
    "EP_UNEMP" = "Unemployment Rate",
    "EP_UNINSUR" = "No Health Insurance"
  )
  
  # Compute totals for info boxes
  total_tracts <- nrow(svi)
  total_population <- sum(st_drop_geometry(svi)$E_TOTPOP, na.rm=TRUE)
  total_housing <- sum(st_drop_geometry(svi)$E_HU, na.rm=TRUE)
  total_households <- sum(st_drop_geometry(svi)$E_HH, na.rm=TRUE)
  
  # Create a reactive dataframe
  portlandsvi <- reactive({svi %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% select(input$variable) %>% pull() %>% as.numeric() }) 
  
  # Set colors
  pal <- reactive({
    colorNumeric("viridis", domain = portlandsvi(), alpha = 0.3, reverse = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles(provider = basemap_providers[[input$basemap]]) %>% 
      addPolygons(
        data = filtered_data(),
        fillColor = ~ pal()(portlandsvi()),
        weight = 0.5,
        opacity = 0.5,
        fillOpacity = ~ fillOpacity,
        smoothFactor = 0.2,
        color = "black",
        label = ~ if (input$variable %in% c("RPL_THEMES","RPL_THEME1","RPL_THEME2","RPL_THEME3",
                                            "RPL_THEME4","E_TOTPOP","E_HU","E_HH")) {
          paste0(variable_labels[[input$variable]], ": ", round(portlandsvi(), 2))
        } else {
          paste0(variable_labels[[input$variable]], ": ", round(portlandsvi(), 2),"%")
        },
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = NULL,
          textsize = "10px",
          direction = "auto",
          opacity = 1,
          textOnly = FALSE
        ),
        # Tooltip for Census Tract
        highlight = highlightOptions(
          color = "white",
          weight = 2.5,
          bringToFront = TRUE
        ),
        # Tooltip for census tract
        popup = ~ paste(
          "<div style='font-size: 10px;'>",
          "<strong>Census Tract: </strong>", str_remove(NAMELSAD, "Census Tract"), "<br/>",
          "<strong>Population: </strong>", formatC(E_TOTPOP, format = "d", big.mark = ","), "<br/>",
          "<strong>Housing Units: </strong>", formatC(E_HU, format = "d", big.mark = ","), "<br/>",
          "<strong>Households: </strong>", formatC(E_HH, format = "d", big.mark = ","), "<br/>",
          "<strong>City: </strong>", CITY
        ),
        popupOptions = popupOptions(
          autoPan = TRUE,
          closeButton = TRUE
        )
      ) %>% 
      addLegend(
        position = "topright",
        pal = pal(),
        values = filtered_data()[[input$variable]],
        title = variable_labels[[input$variable]],
        opacity = 0.8,
        labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = "", digits = 2)
      ) %>% 
      setView(lng = -70.2110, lat = 43.6770, zoom = 12) 
  })

I created fillOpacity column and added to the dataset as an alternative way to solve this problem but it did not work.
Sorry for the very long code and thank you so much for your kind help and expertise.

Hard to say without a minimal reproducible data set to test on, but have you tried specifying the opacity argument within highlightOptions()? Not sure if that's a typo also, as highlight is not one of the arguments accepted by addPolygons().

I just added a github that has a data file. Those are shapefiles.

Can you describe your issue in more detail? I'm not able to replicate the opacity issue - if it's tied to selecting a particular city, the sample data portlandsvi.shp does not appear to have a CITY column for the reactive filter to act on.

Provide a minimal, reproducible example. Links to external data are not acceptable.

I'm so sorry, I just added a new data file that has City Column in the gitHub which is portlandsvi.gpkg. Thank you!

So it appears the issue is caused by the the reactive dataframe object portlandsvi, which filters the svi dataframe instead of filtered_data() reactive dataframe. Switching this line of code to
portlandsvi <- reactive({
    filtered_data() %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% select(input$variable) %>%
      pull() %>% as.numeric()
  })

then makes the domain argument of the color palette match the data argument of addPolygons(). The app.R file linked in the GitHub repo above does not contain the fillOpacity column, so instead of fillOpacity = ~ fillOpacity it's hard coded as fillOpacity = 0.5, so that's what I used to run the example. But I confirmed (by right clicking > Inspect Element) that the fill opacity remains constant (0.5) no matter which city is selected - the colors do not become more solid or more transparent. The server side code (abbreviated to focus just on the leaflet output) is as follows:
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Erase Water
  plsvi <- erase_water(svi, year = 2020) %>% st_make_valid()
  # Transform spatial data to WGS84
  sviwgs84 <- reactive({
    plsvi %>%
      st_transform(crs = 4326)
  })

  # Filter data based on city selection
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    if("All" %in% input$city){
      sviwgs84()
    } else {
      sviwgs84() %>% dplyr::filter(CITY == input$city)
    }
  })

  # Map basemap names to their corresponding provider objects
  basemap_providers <- list(
    "OpenStreetMap" = providers$OpenStreetMap,
    "CartoDB.Positron" = providers$CartoDB.Positron,
    "CartoDB.Voyager" = providers$CartoDB.Voyager,
    "Stadia.StamenToner" = providers$Stadia.StamenToner
  )

  # Define the variable-label mapping using the choices vector
  variable_labels <- list(
    "RPL_THEMES" = "Overall SVI Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME1" = "Socioeconomic Status Theme Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME2" = "Household Characteristics Theme Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME3" = "Racial & Ethnic Minority Status Theme Ranking",
    "RPL_THEME4" = "Housing Type & Transportation Theme Ranking",
    "E_TOTPOP" = "Population Estimate",
    "E_HU" = "Housing Units Estimate",
    "E_HH" = "Households Estimate",
    "EP_AGE17" = "Age 17 & Younger",
    "EP_AGE65" = "Age 65 & Older",
    "EP_CROWD" = "More People than Rooms",
    "EP_DISABL" = "Population with a Disability",
    "EP_GROUPQ" = "Persons in Group Quarters",
    "EP_HBURD" = "Housing Cost Burden",
    "EP_LIMENG" = "Limited English Speaking",
    "EP_MINRTY" = "Minority",
    "EP_MOBILE" = "Mobile Homes",
    "EP_MUNIT" = "Housing with Multiple Units",
    "EP_NOHSDP" = "No High School Diploma",
    "EP_NOVEH" = "Households with No Vehicles",
    "EP_POV150" = "Below 150% Poverty",
    "EP_SNGPNT" = "Single Parent Households",
    "EP_UNEMP" = "Unemployment Rate",
    "EP_UNINSUR" = "No Health Insurance"
  )

  # Create a reactive dataframe
  portlandsvi <- reactive({
    filtered_data() %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% select(input$variable) %>%
      pull() %>% as.numeric()
  }) # Need to drop geometry first otherwise give error

  # Set colors
  pal <- reactive({
    colorNumeric(
      "viridis",
      domain = portlandsvi(),
      alpha = 0.3,
      reverse = TRUE
    )
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(provider = basemap_providers[[input$basemap]]) %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = filtered_data(),
        fillColor = ~ pal()(portlandsvi()),
        weight = 0.5,
        fillOpacity = 0.5,
        smoothFactor = 0.2,
        color = "black",
        label = ~ if (input$variable %in% c(
          "RPL_THEMES",
          "RPL_THEME1",
          "RPL_THEME2",
          "RPL_THEME3",
          "RPL_THEME4",
          "E_TOTPOP",
          "E_HU",
          "E_HH"
        )) {
          paste0(variable_labels[[input$variable]], ": ", round(portlandsvi(), 2))
        } else {
          paste0(variable_labels[[input$variable]], ": ", round(portlandsvi(), 2), "%")
        },
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = NULL,
          textsize = "10px",
          direction = "auto",
          opacity = 1,
          textOnly = FALSE
        ),
        # Tooltip for Census Tract
        highlight = highlightOptions(
          color = "white",
          weight = 2.5,
          bringToFront = TRUE
        ),
        # Tooltip for census tract
        popup = ~ paste(
          "<div style='font-size: 10px;'>",
          "<strong>Census Tract: </strong>",
          str_remove(NAMELSAD, "Census Tract"),
          "<br/>",
          "<strong>Population: </strong>",
          formatC(E_TOTPOP, format = "d", big.mark = ","),
          "<br/>",
          "<strong>Housing Units: </strong>",
          formatC(E_HU, format = "d", big.mark = ","),
          "<br/>",
          "<strong>Households: </strong>",
          formatC(E_HH, format = "d", big.mark = ",")
        ),
        popupOptions = popupOptions(autoPan = TRUE, closeButton = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      addLegend(
        position = "topright",
        pal = pal(),
        values = portlandsvi(),
        title = variable_labels[[input$variable]],
        opacity = 0.8,
        labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = "", digits = 2)
      ) %>%
      setView(lng = -70.2010,
              lat = 43.6190,
              zoom = 11.2)
  })
}


That works perfect now. Thank you so so much @cristian-vargas.
